# Nonlinear PDE $u_{x}^{2} + u_{y}^{2} - u^{2} = 0$ on a circle

Tags: partial-differential-equations

I have the equation: $u_{y}^{2} + u_{x}^{2} - u^{2} =0$ with characteristic strips as $\frac{dx}{dt} = 2u_{x}$, $\frac{dy}{dt} = 2u_{y}$, $\frac{dz}{dt} = 2u_{x}^{2} + 2u_{y}^{2}$, $\frac{dp}{dt} = 2pz$, and $\frac{dp}{dt} = 2qz$. 
The integral surfaces pass through the circle: $x= \cos(s)$, $y= \sin(s)$, and $z=1$.

I am struggling to find $z(s,t)$ and have found that when $t=0$, $p(s,0)$ is $\pm \cos(s)$ and $q(s,0)$ is $\pm \sin(s)$.

Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: Related post [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/1229289/418542)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

$$u_x^2+u_y^2=u^2\quad\text{with condition }u=1\text{ on }x^2+y^2=1.$$
The change of function $u(x,y)=e^{v(x,y)}$ leads to :
$$v_x^2+v_y^2=1\quad\text{with condition }v=0\text{ on }x^2+y^2=1.$$
Since I am rather lazy I will not copy the solution which is given with full details on pages 21-23 (Example 11) in this pdf : http://www.ehu.eus/luis.escauriaza/apuntes_problemas_y_examene/method-of-characteristics.pdf

The resulte is : $\quad v(x,y)= -1+\sqrt{x^2+y^2}$
$$\boxed{u(x,y)=e^{-1+\sqrt{x^2+y^2}}}$$