# Solving non-linear PDE $(\tfrac{\partial t}{\partial x})^{2}+(\tfrac{\partial t}{\partial y})^{2}=f(y,t)$

Tags: partial-differential-equations, substitution

A solution of the relatively complex problem led to the following
non-linear PDE of the first order

$$\left(\frac{\partial t}{\partial x}\right)^{2}+\left(\frac{\partial t}{\partial y}\right)^{2}=\frac{t^{2}(t-1)^{2}(t^{2}+2t+5)^{2}}{(y(t^{3}+3t-10)+t(t^{2}+5))^{2}}.$$
Unfortunately, the right side is relatively complex and can not be
expressed in the form of $f(y)g(t)$ that is suitable for the substitution
$$dz=\frac{dt}{\sqrt{g(t)}},\qquad z=\int\frac{1}{\sqrt{g(t)}}dt,$$

transfoming PDE
$$\left(\frac{\partial t}{\partial x}\right)^{2}+\left(\frac{\partial t}{\partial y}\right)^{2}=f(y)g(t),$$

into a more simple form of
$$\left(\frac{\partial z}{\partial x}\right)^{2}+\left(\frac{\partial z}{\partial y}\right)^{2}=f(y).$$

Is there any reasonable substitution for PDE of the form
$$\left(\frac{\partial t}{\partial x}\right)^{2}+\left(\frac{\partial t}{\partial y}\right)^{2}=f(y,t),
$$
leading to relatively “simple” Lagrange-Charpit equations that can be applied to the above-mentioned PDE?

Thanks for your help.

Comment: You equation seems to make no sense. Is $t$ an independent variable or is it the dependent variable? Is $x$ an independent variable.

Comment: @MachineLearner: Sorry, but I do not understand your comment.  This is non-linear PDE of the first order. The general form of the solution is $t = F(x, y)$. However, the right side is relatively complex.

Comment: @EditPiAf: Thanks, for your clarification. Taking into account the "complexity" of the right side, how does the substitution look like? I found only elementary eikonal equations with the simple right side... Thanks.

Comment: See [this post](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/1229289/418542) about eikonal eq. with a non-trivial r.h.s